# AdBlock makes TuneIn Radio crash

Tags: applications

Device: galaxy S3
Rom:liquidsmooth 4.4.4

I recently upgraded to liquidsmooth kit kat and as usuall i reinstalled my fav apps.For some reason the app Adfree that i use seems to block tunein from loading the stations.

The app works until you select a station then crashes.If i revert the hosts it plays fine.
I also used different adblockers like the build in liquidsmooth one and the crash happens again.

Is there a way to white list tunein?

Answer (score 1):

Try another software called ad away that has the option to white list apps. Ad block doesn't seem to have the white listing option.

https://f-droid.org/repo/org.adaway_51.apk

Comment: Add a link for the app you suggested. Its really not an accurate answer, the way it is now.